# I get "KeyError: 1" from a simple copy - Python Machine Learning

Tags: python, keyerror

I have no idea why I'm getting this error and I'm working with Mnist btw, and same dataset and functions worked for different models ( LDA i.e.) and this is the same implementation with SVM as model.

```
natural_targets_dict_woae = {}
non_natural_targets_dict_woae = {}
one_number_targets_dict_woae = {}
for ix, series in attacktargets_woae.iterrows():
    natural_targets_dict_woae[ix] = series.argmax()
    non_natural_targets_dict_woae[ix] = series.drop(ix).argmin()
    one_number_targets_dict_woae[ix] = y_test_woae[0]

natural_foolingtargets_woae = np.zeros((y_test_woae.shape[0]))
non_natural_foolingtargets_woae = np.zeros((y_test_woae.shape[0]))
one_number_foolingtargets_woae = np.zeros((y_test_woae.shape[0]))
for n in range(len(natural_foolingtargets_woae)):
    target_woae = y_test_woae[n]
    natural_foolingtargets_woae[n] = natural_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]
    non_natural_foolingtargets_woae[n] = non_natural_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]
    one_number_foolingtargets_woae[n] = one_number_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]

attack_woae.create_one_hot_targets(natural_foolingtargets_woae.astype(np.int))
attack_woae.attack_to_max_epsilon(targeted_gradient, epsilon_number)
natural_scores_woae = attack_woae.scores

attack_woae.create_one_hot_targets(non_natural_foolingtargets_woae.astype(np.int))
attack_woae.attack_to_max_epsilon(targeted_gradient, epsilon_number)
non_natural_scores_woae = attack_woae.scores

attack_woae.create_one_hot_targets(one_number_foolingtargets_woae.astype(np.int))
attack_woae.attack_to_max_epsilon(targeted_gradient, epsilon_number)
one_target_scores_woae = attack_woae.scores
```

**Error:**

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-83-e52f71235839> in <module>
     12 for n in range(len(natural_foolingtargets_woae)):
     13     target_woae = y_test_woae[n]
---> 14     natural_foolingtargets_woae[n] = natural_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]
     15     non_natural_foolingtargets_woae[n] = non_natural_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]
     16     one_number_foolingtargets_woae[n] = one_number_targets_dict_woae[target_woae]

KeyError: 1
```

Comment: It seems that the key `1` is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: try putting `print(natural_targets_dict_woae)` before `for n in ...` loop. What is the output?